# How to revert back to original hashcode?

Tags: java, hashcode, overriding

In java,How can we get the original hashcode value of an object, if the hashcode method is already overridden?

Comment: maybe provide a little more context into the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`System.identityHashCode(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29) method.

> Returns the same hash code for the given object as would be returned by the default method `hashCode()`, whether or not the given object's class overrides `hashCode()`. The hash code for the `null` reference is zero.

Comment: Why would `#` be used for naming the method given that it is static? Wouldn't the `.` be used?

Answer (score 1):

For the `Object` hashcode, use [`System.identityHashCode(Object o)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29). This static method will provide `Object#hashCode`-like hashCodes, or `0` for null.

Answer (score 0):

System.identityHashCode(object) should provide you the original hashcode, no matter what the overridden hashcode() methods returns.